# Create a list of matrices that measure differences in growth rates in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

Suppose I have the following list:

```
$`1990`
  cntry year growth
1     1 1990      1
2     2 1990      2
3     3 1990     14

$`1991`
  cntry year growth
4     1 1991      6
5     2 1991      5
6     3 1991      7
```

Code to create the list:

```
cntry<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
year<-c(1990,1990,1990,1991,1991,1991)
growth<-c(1,2,14,6,5,7)

a<-data.frame(cntry,year,growth)
a.split<-split(a, as.factor(a$year))
```

What I want to create is a list of matrices which measure the differences in the growth rates between two countries.

1. In the respective matrix, the difference in growth rates should only be calculated if the growth rate of the country in the column
   is higher than the one of the country in the row.
2. If the growth rate in the column is equal or smaller than the one of
   the country in the row, then the matrix should display a value of 0.
3. If there is at least one country in the combination with a NA value,
   then the matrix should display a 0 in the respective field.

The result should look as followed:

```
$`1990`
  1 2  3
1 0 1 13
2 0 0 12
3 0 0  0

$`1991`
  1 2 3
1 0 0 1
2 1 0 2
3 0 0 0
```

Any help is highly welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `outer`:

```
> lapply(a.split, function(x) t(outer(x$growth, x$growth, function(u,v) ifelse(u>v, u-v, 0))))
#$`1990`
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1   13
#[2,]    0    0   12
#[3,]    0    0    0

#$`1991`
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    1
#[2,]    1    0    2
#[3,]    0    0    0
```

Comment: works perfectly as always, thanks @colonel beauvel ! One last question: How would you ensure that, if there is a NA value in a combination, a 0 is pasted instead?

Comment: I feel not to understand correctly, you mean an NA in the growth column of one of your data.frame in a.split? In this case you can do this `lst=lapply(a.split, function(u) {u[is.na(u)]=0;u})` and then apply the outer one line script.